# Cannot catch error, it is instead printed to the console

Tags: python, python-3.x, upnp, miniupnpc

I am detecting whether the external IP has changed with `miniupnpc`. And during my testing I've noticed that when I turn off Wi-Fi (disconnect my pc from the internet) I get an error which I cannot catch with the exception.

It appears to be printed to the console.

```
u = miniupnpc.UPnP()
u.discoverdelay = config.svc_upnp_disc_delay

try:
    discover = u.discover()
    print(discover, 'device(s) detected')

    if discover:
        u.selectigd()

        while True:
            stat_info, stat_port, stat_error = u.statusinfo()
            if stat_info == 'Connected':

                if u.lanaddr != os.environ.get(config.envr_name_int_addr):
                    os.environ[config.envr_name_int_addr] = u.lanaddr

                ext_ip = u.externalipaddress()
                if ext_ip != os.environ.get(config.envr_name_ext_addr):
                    os.environ[config.envr_name_ext_addr] = ext_ip

                print('+', end=' ', flush=True)

            else:
                print('-', end=' ', flush=True)
                if stat_info != os.environ.get(config.envr_svc_status):
                    os.environ[config.envr_svc_status] = stat_info

            time.sleep(5)

except Exception as e:
    print('Exception :', e)
```

This is the error:

```
sendto: Network is unreachable
sendto: Network is unreachable
sendto: Network is unreachable
sendto: Network is unreachable
```

Is there any way I can catch this so I can log it in a log file instead of the console?

And what is causing it in the first place...because I am not printing it?

Comment: First of all, what is the origin of the exception?
It might be that the package itself takes care of its own Exceptions.
Do you have any traceback?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that there are 4 errors being logged indicates that your try...except block might not work correctly.

Try using BaseException instead of Exception in your except clause.

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't catch anything also.